# How can I send sensor data from ROS to CrateDB via FIROS?

Tags: json, middleware, ros, fiware, cratedb

I have a vehicle with **ROS** installed. How can I send the sensor data of this vehicle to **CrateDB** *via FIROS*?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the diagram available in [1], the FIROS component does not send data to CrateDB but to the Orion Context Broker. I suggest you to have a look at the FIROS example from [2].

Once you have your data in the Orion Context Broker, which is the only mandatory component of every Powered by FIWARE architecture, heterogeneous data consumers and providers can interact with them using the standard NGSI API.

In turn, the FIWARE catalague [3] offers a number of IoT agents and data connectors to ease the integration of heterogeneous technologies and protocols with the Context Broker using NGSI.

CrateDB is one of the technologies that can be easily integrated using existing NGSI Data Connectors (e.g., QuantumLeap). A working example which illustrates the integration between the Orion Context Broker and CrateDB using QuantumLeap is available at [4].

I hope this helps you make progress towards your goals.

[1] FIROS github: https://github.com/iml130/firos

[2] FIROS Example: https://firos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/turtlesim-example.html

[3] FIWARE Catalogue: https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue

[4] CrateDB Example: https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/time-series-data/index.html